# How show post only from after custom date

Tags: custom-field, date

I have custom post type. In this custom post type I have custom field with date in format: 23/09/2012

How to show only posts, which currently date is before date from these custom field?

Sory for my english.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `query_posts()` or a new `WP_Query` object. Here's an example:

```
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => 'my_date_field_key',
           'value' => date( 'd/m/Y' ),
           'compare' => '<',
           'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
) );

if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    // your loop code here
    the_title('<h2>','</h2>');

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

**NOTE:**

If you want to order by date this is a little trickier unless you store the date as a unix timestamp. Then you can orderby meta_value_num as it's just a number.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. unfortunately it's not working for me. My code: <code>asdas</code>

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. unfortunately it's not working for me. My code:



query_posts( array(
   'post_type' => 'wydarzenia',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
          'key' => 'data_zakonczenia_wydarzenia',
          'value' => date( 'd/m/Y' ),
          'compare' => '<',
          'type' => 'DATE'
       )
   )
) );

if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

// my loop code here

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_query();



and not working. I tried with another date format, but still not working?

Comment: Where it says '// your loop code here' you have to pu in something for it to output eg. `the_title()`

Comment: I would recommend storing dates as unix timestamps too, let me know if you make that change and I'll update the example.